# QT Creator Bluetooth Advertising on Android Device

Tags: java, android, qt, bluetooth, qt-creator

i want to write my bluetooth observer code with Qt Creator. With android studio SDK, i can read custom advertising data with this callback fonction:

```
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback;

{
    mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {

            Data = scanRecord;
            // Convert Hex to String
            int temp, digit1,digit0;
            stringData="";
            for (int i = 1; i < Data.length; i++)
            {
                temp = Data[i] & 0xff;
                digit1 = temp >> 0x04;
                digit0 = temp & 0x0f;
                stringData += String.valueOf(digit1) +    String.valueOf(digit0);
            }

            RSSI = rssi;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                    mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    };

}
```

With Qt Creator, i want to do the same thing, but i don't find the method or function to read advertising data. I can read address and name but not the custom user data. All suggestions are welcome.